# detecting duplicate in columns of a 2D array

Tags: c++, algorithm

I would like an algorithm that goes through a 2D array and guarantees that each column has all distinct numbers. If a dupe is found in the array it should be replaced with a random number. The random number must also preserve the uniqueness.

If we put a random number, the whole column, should be unique.

is it possible to get an O(N) solution too ?

Comment: What if the random value happens to be a dupe?

Comment: are your colums ordered or not? (if there are duplicate numbers always consecutive or not)

Comment: @aaronman it should be replaced it with another number.

Comment: @nio the columns are not ordered, not always consecutive.

Comment: @Mahmoud I think that my answer is the best you are likely to find, try coding it yourself before asking for help

Comment: @aaronman why the random number might be a dupe? you still add it to the set, and if the size does not change, randomize again and again. P.s. it is also nice to inform the owner of the answer if something is wrong and not just downvote.

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie I apologize that criticism is incorrect, the way you checked is just strange, but I am 100% percent sure that my solution is faster than yours

Comment: What is a "duplicate"? A single cell in one column matching a cell in another column, but not necessarily the same row? Do they need to be in the same row? Does the entire column have to match? In the same order? Your question isn't precise enough to answer well...

Comment: @twalberg he explained better in comments, only columns must have unique elements, now I've been ranting though because he accepted the clearly inferior solution

Comment: anyone know why this was put on hold

Comment: @aaronman your algo is better, but next time be a little more patient before writing bad things about other people.

Comment: I didn't write anything bad other than the random number dupe thing

Comment: @Mahmoud my solution is O(n), I tried to edit your question to get it reopened but it may not have worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I can think of is to make an `unordered_map<int,bool>` for each column, iterate through the column and if you see a number for the first time set the map to true, if the value is already true it's a dupe replace it with a random number. Then check the random number in the map and do the same thing, if it's also a dupe you will have to replace it with a random number again. This algo will like run in linear time, however because of the random number dupe possibility it could run infinitely.

**pseudo code**

```
2d_array // assume M rows by N cols
array_of_hashtables // N length
for each col
    for each row
       if array_of_hashtables[2d_array[row][col]] == false
           set it to true
       else
           do
               set 2d_array[row][col] to random
           while array_of_hashtables[2d_array[row][col]] == true
    end
end
```

not a huge fan of writing pseudo code but this is about right

Comment: can you prove your idea with pseudo code ?

Comment: Sure but it's really better if you do it yourself

Answer (score 1):

Make a `std::set` and insert step by step elements of every column while checking the size of the set. If the size changes the inserted value is not a duplicate, if it does just randomize  a value and add it again to the set. If size changes, you can continue.

Comment: `std::set` does not have constant time access

Comment: After that I need to copy the columns to the array again ?

Comment: @Mahmoud no, why? you just use the `std::set` to chech for duplicates. You copy the columns to the set.

Comment: @aaronman it is just logarithmic complexity for `std::insert` and constant for `std::size`

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie I think I can replace the set with an array ? I also want the algorithm in actionscript...

Comment: I know that Alexandru that's why I made the comment and @Mahmoud if you want the algo in actionscript you should have tagged the question for it

Comment: @Mahmoud no, sets chech for duplicates on their own. If your set is `1 2 3` if you try to add a `2` the size will not change leaving the set `1 2 3` those with the same size.

Comment: +1 for a neat solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the heck of it, here is an implementation of [Alexandru Barbarosie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2339141/alexandru-barbarosie)'s solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int L = 3;
    int W = 3;
    int R = 3;    
    int a[L][W];    
    srand(time(NULL));     
    for (int i = 0; i < L; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < W; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = rand() % R + 1;
            cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }    
    cout << endl;

    set<int> s;    
    int n = 0;    
    for (int j = 0; j < W; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < L; i++)
        {
            s.insert(a[i][j]);
            if (s.size() != n)
                n = s.size();
            else
                a[i--][j] = rand() % R + 1;
        }
        s.clear();
        n = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < L; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < W; j++)
            cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: In c++11 you should use c++'s random engines rather than the old c style of doing it

Comment: what does that mean ? a[i--][j] = rand() % R + 1; why i-- ?

Comment: @Mahmoud he used `i--` because he wants to keep `i` at the same number so the loop checks if the random number is a dupe, the `rand() % R + 1` produces a random number between 1 and 3 which I'm guessing is not what you want